# When does hook_field_storage_details_alter() fire?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I need to modify the field storage details so some additional data can be stored with a form field. I found [hook_field_storage_details_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_details_alter/7), but it doesn't seem to fire. When is this hook used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that invokes both `hook_field_storage_details()` and `hook_field_storage_details_alter()` is [_field_info_prepare_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/_field_info_prepare_field/7), which is indirectly called from the following functions:

- [field_info_cache_clear()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_cache_clear/7)
- [field_info_extra_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_extra_fields/7)
- [field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7)
- [field_info_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7)
- [field_info_field_by_id()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_by_id/7)
- [field_info_field_by_ids()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_by_ids/7)
- [field_info_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)
- [field_info_instances()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7)

In other words, all times information about a field is required, that hook is used.
As Clive points out, [_field_info_collate_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/_field_info_collate_fields/7), the function that directly calls  `_field_info_prepare_field()`, caches the information returned by those hooks, which means they are not always invoked; they are invoked when the cached data don't exist, or have been removed. This makes `hook_field_storage_details_alter()` used in a similar way to `hook_menu_alter()`, which is called only when the menu definitions need to be rebuild, and not all times Drupal is retrieving the menu definitions given by all the enabled modules.

Comment: It's only invoked if the cache has been cleared, otherwise the cached version is used and the hook will never actually be called

Comment: That is correct. I should have pointed that out, as I didn't report which function directly calls `_field_info_prepare_field()`.

Comment: awesome! that's really helpful. However, for some reason, when I change the values in $details, it doesn't actually save those changes. Basically what I am trying to do is add an additional database column for a boolean (checkbox) to the image field. I got the database altered hook_field_update_field(), however the node_form doesn't seem to save the checkbox, I was thinking this had to do with the storage details? or am I missing something? when i look into hook_node_presave(), everything looks like it should, but no save. :(

Comment: `hook_field_storage_details()` can return details about the schema used for the field, but that is different from the form fields used to show the field value, and how the form field value is saved in the database.

Comment: oo, I assumed that since $details is being passed by reference, it could be modified using that hook. How would you go about telling drupal that their is an extra database column to save to? @Clive

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is taking the extra checkbox's data and saving it separately (on presave or something), however, that seems rather messy.

Comment: @DavidBarratt Probably you should be implementing a new field, and a widget to use with that field. Altering the storage details doesn't assure the widget used by the existing field is able to show the extra data you associate with the field, or the extra data is correctly saved.

Comment: rrr! that seems silly that you can modify the database, the widget and the formatter, but you can't modify the field's storage. Should I just copy the default Image module and change the namespace? thanks! also, what about existing data? @Clive

Comment: @DavidBarratt You *can* specify an extra column for a field but it's probably going to be more hassle than its worth, I'd really advise rolling your own field as kiamlaluno suggests. Even though it goes against the DRY principle in this instance it's going to save you a lot of time and head-against-wall banging. Personally I'd build up each required function in the new module one at a time as there'll be things inside most functions (not just the name) that will need to change slightly

Comment: ok, and if I have this right, this wouldn't be a hassle if the hook specified in the question actually altered the details (like I assumed it did)? @Clive

Comment: It seems like a bug that this hook isn't changing the storage details like it should be. @Clive

Answer (score 1):

It's invoked from [`_field_info_prepare_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/_field_info_prepare_field/7), which in turn is only called by a single function, [`field_info_collate_fields()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/_field_info_collate_fields/7).

This function is in turn called by a fair few, all of which are part of the [Field Info API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/group/field_info/7):

- field_info_cache_clear()
- field_info_extra_fields()
- field_info_field()
- field_info_fields()
- And a few more (have a look at the "10 functions call _field_info_collate_fields()" bit on the [`field_info_collate_fields()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/_field_info_collate_fields/7)).

Looking at `field_info_collate_fields()` it seems that `_field_info_prepare_field()` is only called after Drupal's caches have been cleared (i.e. when there's no available cache data):

```
if ($cached = cache_get('field_info_fields', 'cache_field')) {
  $info = $cached->data;
}
else {
  // _field_info_prepare_field() is called a few lines after this
```

So I think the answer to your question is that the hook is invoked after you've cleared Drupal's cache.